# NPM install stucks

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

in last few days I noticed I basically cannot use npm. It get stuck every time I try to install the deps of a project.
For example https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

It gets stuck every time on the message `finalize: sill finalize \node_modules\ajv`

I tried to turn on http log and turn off spin

```
$ npm set spin false
$ npm set loglevel http
```

- windows 7 x64
- node v8.4.0
- npm v5.5.1

here the console error
[image]

Comment: Please also mention npm and nodejs version.

Comment: maybe issue in npm version please install other version and try again

Comment: Once I noticed the problem I updated npm (few minutes ago) it didn't solved. So I already tried 2 npm version

Comment: can you paste here npm error log

Comment: can u paste full error log in you question?

Comment: in console you can find

Comment: i edited the question, here the error in npm verbose mode

Comment: Can you try running your shell or command prompt as administrator and then  do the npm install  ?

Comment: that screenshot is already from a cmd as admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrade npm, clearing cache, forced uninstall **none worked**.

Eventually **I solved** manually deleting

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\npm
%APPDATA%\Roaming\npm-cache
```

then

```
npm --force uninstall npm -g
npm install npm@5.0.3 -g
```

Comment: Did you to removed package-lock and node-module folder ? Maybe it can be solved only by removed package-lock and project node-module.